Remove un used files from core php project
I want to remove unused php files from my core php project. I have tried various static analysis tools like phpstan, phpDocumentor etc but it gives only the unused functions etc. I need to have the files which are not in use. Can anyone please suggest how can I achieve this ?

Although not directly what you are asking for, after you remove these unused functions you'll eventually end up with an empty file which is easy to find and delete

If you are writing a library, a class not being referenced within your project does not imply it won't be used by your users.
Write unit tests and set up a test coverage report. Then you will have a better idea whether those uncovered lines of codes are actually "unused" in your situation.
